# screen: how do I move a window in between 2 other windows

Tags: gnu-screen

In [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is there a way to put a window in between 2 others instead of swapping?

Here is what I have

```
1 - I want this to become #2
2 - I want this to become #3
3 - I want this to become #1
```

If I go to screen #3 and enter the command ":number 1", the new order is

```
1 - I want this to become #1
2 - I want this to become #3
3 - I want this to become #2
```

Obviously with one more command, I can get what I want.  However, when I have 15 windows it is a major pain.

Comment: ok - I've updated the question.  Is it clear enough now?

Comment: The question is off topic here, but if you make it a bit more clear, it could possibly be migrated.

Comment: oh, sorry.  I thought this was the right stackexchange to ask questions about gnu commands.  Which one would that be?  Was it unclear because I hadn't mentioned screen enough (I just added a link in the first sentence)?  I would think that anyone who uses screen could tell what I'm trying to do.  Thanks.

Comment: The question makes sense now. I think somebody with sufficient privileges should migrate it to unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be no single screen command to do it. However I came up with this script, that can do it by executing enough `number` commands in a row to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

L="$1"
for N in $(eval echo "{$1..$2}")
do
    screen -X at "$L" number "$N"
    L="$N"
done
```

This can be run from any window within the screen and takes two arguments, the source and destination number of a window to be moved. The source or destination window can match your current window number.

I could find no way to query screen about active and existing window numbers from a script. So I could not make the script default to moving the active window.